# C# copy gridview contents to clipboard

Tags: .net, gridview, clipboard

I have several gridviews. In each of them, I copy the contents to the clipboard using code like this:

GV_Master.SelectAll();
DataObject dataObj = GV_Master.GetClipboardContent();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, true);
GV_Master.ClearSelection();

On most cases this works as intended, copying the entire contents of the Gridview to the clipboard. In one case it copies only the cell in which I right clicked to invoke the context menu that calls the code above. The thing that is obviously different is that the gridviews that work have a data source, and the one that doesn't has rows that I individually populate. However, if what is being copied is the contents of the clipboard rather than the datasource, I don't see why this should matter.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the gridview multiselect to true, and selectionmode to fullrowselect seems to have done the trick. Silly to have missed this before.